# What is the difference between npm package cdk and aws-cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk, npx

In shell scripts interacting with the AWS CDK Toolkit, I often see both `npx -- cdk` and `npx -- aws-cdk`. Apparently, there are two npm packages [`cdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cdk) and [`aws-cdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cdk). What is the difference between these two?

Moreover, I make confusing observations when interacting with these two packages.

```bash
npx -- cdk --version     # output: Need to install the following packages: cdk@2.32.1
npx -- aws-cdk --version # output: Need to install the following packages: aws-cdk@2.32.1
```

Since neither package is installed locally, both commands want to install the corresponding package, fine.

```bash
npm install -g cdk@2.32.0
npx -- cdk --version     # output: 2.32.0 (build 00e0c2d)
npx -- aws-cdk --version # output: Need to install the following packages: aws-cdk@2.32.1
```

After installing `cdk` locally, `npx -- cdk` executes the local package and `npx -- aws-cdk` still wants to install `aws-cdk`, also fine.

```bash
npm install -g aws-cdk@2.32.0
npx -- cdk --version     # output: 2.32.0 (build 00e0c2d)
npx -- aws-cdk --version # output: Need to install the following packages: aws-cdk@2.32.1
```

Now it gets confusing. Although we locally installed `aws-cdk` rather than `cdk`, `npx -- cdk` still executes some local package and `npx -- aws-cdk` still wants to install `aws-cdk`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The [`aws-cdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-cdk) package provides a `cdk` command, the entry point to the AWS Cloud Development Kit.

When you install `aws-cdk` package in `node_modules/.bin` there is a `cdk` command installed.
This allows one to use `cdk` command inside `package.json` scripts.

The `cdk` command is [also the only command added to `.bin` by aws-cdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/package.json#L6).

As per all of the documentation, in order to interact with AWS CDK from CLI, one should use `cdk` command. That is even though the package name is `aws-cdk`.

Now, the `npx` provides a convenient way to run a command from a package regardless if it is already installed.

This works in the most straightforward way when the package name matches the command name it provides. This is not the case for `aws-cdk`.
In order to fix that, and allow anyone to run `npx cdk ...` the AWS CDK decided to publish a package named [`cdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cdk). This is a small wrapper around `cdk` [command provided by `aws-cdk` package](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/cdk/bin/cdk).

Comment: To me it seems that `aws-cdk` is the preferred way, and not `cdk`. At least the documentation always uses `npx aws-cdk` and not `npx cdk`, e.g. see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-typescript.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with-cdk-javascript.html) or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html).

Comment: Yes. What meant is that without using npx the documentation will use cdk in CLI. It's only in the context of npx where aws-cdk is used in CLI. I presume that because of that the cdk package was published just in case.